# Create Athena on S3 , need to truncate reload the underlying data in the s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Iam trying to setup athena queries for my users, but we need to refresh underlying data.

Not sure if we can refresh data from s3 like truncate and reload but no downtime for athena users.

Answer (score 0):

When an Amazon Athena query is executed, it reads through the files in the directory location associated with the table definition.

If you wish to update underlying data, simply update the files in Amazon S3. The new data shall be used when the next Athena query is issued.

If you are worried about "down time" while you are updating/replacing the data, then you could put the new data in a different folder. Once it is ready, modify the table definition to point to the new location instead of the previous location.

See: [ALTER TABLE SET LOCATION - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-set-location.html)